# One-To-One relationship between Account and Campaign Modules in SugarCRM CE 6.5.4

Tags: php, crm, sugarcrm

I want to create one-to-one relationship between Account and Campaign modules (one-to-many relationship already exists by default). After that I want to show a field (Autocomplete or search) in campaign edit view to select related account to that campaign.

I am not able to find the right path weather to change existing one-to-many relation or create new. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Please guide me how to define "VarDefs" definition if possible, I want to do this at code level without studio.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a new one-to-one relationship thru Studio. See this guide for more details...

http://support.sugarcrm.com/02_Documentation/01_Sugar_Editions/05_Sugar_Community_Edition/Sugar_Community_Edition_6.5/Sugar_Community_Edition_Administration_Guide_6.5.0/07_Developer_Tools#Creating_Relationships